# What is the difference between "我还没打算" and "我还没决定"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

In a question-response practice, the question is "你暑假要去旅游吗"? Why is the right response "我还没决定", not "我还没打算"?

Comment: 8 answers and only one upvote.... *say wut?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"打算" is equivalent to "plan", and "我还没打算" is usually used in following forms:

"我还没打算 去旅游", "我还没打算 吃饭", "我还没 这种 打算", "我还没打算 to do something".

Comment: Do you mean "我还没打算" is not okay because I have to say "去旅游" after it? Per your explanation, it seems both "我还没打算" and "我还没决定" are correct responses, right?

Comment: If you say "我还没打算", he may think you will "去旅游", just don't have a detailed planning about this trip; Or he may think you will not "去旅游". As we see, "我还没打算" sometimes doesn't give a definitely response, i.e. one can be confused about the different meanings

Comment: In general, if someone ask a "Yes/No" question, you can answer "Yes","No", or "我还 没决定/不确定/没想好", and you should add some words after/before "打算" to make you response definitely.

Comment: This answer actually doesn't compare the difference between 打算 and 决定 ... any way poster can update it to add information about 决定?

Answer (score 4):

In the narrow sense of a q&a practice, I would say that by saying ‘我还没打算’ you are not answering the question *if* you want／are going to travel (你暑假要去旅游吗), while 我还没决定 (I haven't made up my mind yet) is a very clean answer.

我还没打算 is like 'I didn't plan (the trip) yet'. Also, compare this answer to something like: '暑假我没有计划' (I have no plans for the summer holidays).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I am confused why "我还没打算" doesn't answer the question. The question is "Will you travel during summer break?". The response is "I haven't planned to". Could you please explain more? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

“我还没打算“ literally means "I do not have intentions yet." 
“我还没决定“ literally means "I have not decided yet."

When someone asks you if you are going on a trip for vacation, and you don't actually know if you are going or not, both are logically true. However pragmatically:
The former means that you are currently not planning to do so, though the situation may change in the future. In that, you are expressing something like "Not for now, though I may." in which you mean that you have decided not to go on a trip given the current circumstances, although this decision may change.
The latter means that you have no specific answer to the question. In that, you are expressing something like "Maybe, maybe not." in which each situation has an unknown probability of happening, and you have no decision at all.

In fact both answers are correct and practical. However, 打算 as a verb means "to plan", so the sentence may as well be interpreted as "I have not planned yet.", which can be further extended to "I have not planned on trips in my holidays yet.", which is not what you mean and doesn't sound natural (I believe that this is the reason it is wrong) since 打算 as a verb is most often accompanied by an action you are (perhaps not) planning to do. To make it clear that 打算 is a noun, simply add a determiner: "this". “我还没有**这个**打算“ would more precisely mean that "I do not have **these (such)** intentions yet." Also, since it means that the situation is temporary, it may sometimes sound more natural if you add "temporarily": “我**暂时**还没有**这个**打算“.

Comment: I think I understand what you said. Since "打算" as a verb is most often accompanied by an action, it's better to say "去旅游” after "我还没打算" to make the meaning clear. Otherwise, "打算" is taken as a noun and "这个" should be added. But my new question is that 决定 is also a verb most often accompanied by an action. So does "我还没决定" also sound unnatural?

Comment: The problem is how inflexible 打算 is. It may always be legitimate to use it wherever 决定 can be used, but in practice anything besides "I plan(ed) to ..." is more or less not very natural unless you are using it as a noun. 决定 is more flexible and can be used alone without any problem.

Comment: Also note that when answering a question like "What plans do you have for your future?" 你对未来有什么打算？ the answer is likely "I have not planned yet." which is appropriately expressed by 我还没打算, where 打算 is a verb. I did indeed say that it may be unnatural to use it this way, but in this case it may be more natural to correspond to the question as closely as possible. When the question uses 打算(a noun in the question) you use it in your response too (though as a verb).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see the difference between 打算 and 决定 better with the following question:

> Q: 你暑假想要做什么?
>  What do you plan to do during the holidays.
>
> A: 我还没做任何**打算**。
>  I haven't make any plans.
>
> B: 我**打算**去旅游，但还没**决定**去哪里。
>  I plan to travel, but haven't
>   decide where to go.

In your practice question, because 旅游 has been proposed by the asker as a *specific* plan for the holiday, 决定 would be an appropriate answer if the answerer has thought about it but not come to a decision. It is *not wrong* to use 打算 if the answerer has not even entertained that idea of travelling.

In any case, without further context, there is no way to tell whether the answerer has considered how to spend his holiday to know which would be the "correct" response.

Comment: I agree with you. In real life there is no "incorrect" response. But in a test, there is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "我还没打算" is absolutely wrong; both responses are fine.

"我还没打算" does sound a little unnatural/ambiguous because the question is suggesting a plan and a spot-on response should acknowledge it by saying "I'll consider" or "I have decided" or "that's not the plan".

By responding with "我还没打算" (I don't have a plan yet), it is unclear whether it means "I don't have a plan for the summer yet, so travel is an option" or "I don't have a plan for travel yet". Either way it's not a straight-forward answer to the question.

But you can say "我还没有**这样的**打算" (I don't have *such* plan yet), then it becomes clear - "I don't have plan to travel yet". This response sounds natural and is actually commonly heard.

On the other hand, saying "我还没决定" implies "I have already thought about travel before you ask, but have not decided yet" which is usually used in a follow-up conversation. The semantic is also clear and answer the question well.

Comment: For native-English speakers, it is hard to tell which combo sounds natural and which doesn't, since they both sound the same to us. What the person tried to say is: I haven't planned to do so, not "I don't have a plan for the summer".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the conversation you provided, I guess that when the guy in the exercise asks you 你暑假要去旅游吗, she/he probably knows that you have already planned the trip, or already had the idea in your mind. So she/he is asking for your final decision, therefore 决定 is used.

However, in my opinion, 我还没打算 should also be correct, where you could say 还没这个打算 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually as a Chinese, I think "我还没打算" is OK in practical use. Then I asked 5 of my classmates and they think the same . 
However, they also mentioned there might be a little difference that "我还没打算" means "I haven't think of it (at all)", while "我还没决定" shows that you have thought of it but haven't decided whether to travel.

Answer (score 0):

我还没有“打算”

you mean  I have no  plan/idea(打算)

“打算” in this sentence be a noun!

but in chinese “打算” usually be a verb!

Answer (score 0):

没决定 = hesitate
没打算 = don't have such a plan.

(决定 or 打算) + 没(not)

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize so it can show whether I really understand. (If not, please correct me.)

1. In practical use (real life), both are fine. But "我还没打算" might be ambiguous, since different listeners might interpret it differently.
2. "我还没决定" is more direct to answer the question. In a test when both exist, "我还没决定" is preferred as "correct" response.

Thank you very much for all your help! 谢谢。